# How To Read and Write Delphi 2010 RibbonApplicationMenuBar Recent Items To A File

Tags: delphi, ribbon

How do you read and write `RibbonApplicationMenuBar` recent items to a file or an INI file?

The help file is not very helpful for getting at the list of recent item strings to save and reload the recent items.  I can add items to the recent items list by `Ribbon1.AddRecentItem( APathFilename)` and open the file associated with the recent item with the `RecentItemClick` event but I can not figure out how to save and reload recent filenames to the recent items list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TRibbonApplicationMenuBar](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/RibbonActnMenus_TRibbonApplicationMenuBar.html) has a [RecentItems](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/RibbonActnMenus_TRibbonApplicationMenuBar_RecentItems.html) property, which provides access to a [list](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/RibbonActnMenus_TOptionItems_Items.html) of [each recent item](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/RibbonActnMenus_TOptionItem.html).

```
// example code - untested.
RibbonApplicationMenuBar1.RecentItems.Items[1].Caption;
```

Another example for looping though each item.

```
// example code - untested.  
var
  count : Integer;
begin
  For count := 1 to RibbonApplicationMenuBar1.RecentItems.Items.Count do
  begin
    ShowMessage(RibbonApplicationMenuBar1.RecentItems.Items[count].Caption);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I do not have a copy of Delphi with me to test, so the above code maybe incorrect ;o)